# How to make drop down lists next to each other without any spacing or padding

Tags: html, asp.net, combobox, aspxcombobox

[image: The Image Click here.]

my code for the drop down items is below. i have padding:0. however. it is still causing a space in between my three drop down list items. i want no space and for all of them to be exactly 150px width. not sure why it still has a space. I guess i am thinking too much.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="150px" style="padding:0">
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Borough</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>ZipCode</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Address No</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Street</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Freeform</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" Width="150px"  style="padding:0">
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Borough</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>ZipCode</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Address No</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Street</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Freeform</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" Width="150px"  style="padding:0">
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Borough</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>ZipCode</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Address No</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Street</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Freeform</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: You can try `margin: 0` (or `margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0` if you want to keep the top and bottom margins).

Comment: remove padding and just have margin as 0. i tried it still looks like the image i just added to the question. i tried your edit as well still the same output as the image above

Comment: Maybe `margin: 0px !important;` then.

Comment: i tried it with the comment above its still the same. Here is my code. `<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="150px" style="margin: 0px !important;">` and the other `<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" Width="150px"  style="margin: 0px !important;">`

Comment: lol i tried it all. not sure why its still spaced out.

Comment: I found something that works in Firefox but not in Chrome. This is strange...

Comment: oh wow. haha. this is why the browser gods told us not to have too many browsers or thy developers shall suffer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space between the DropDownLists comes from the spaces (or line breaks) in the markup. You can try the following markup to remove them:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="150px">
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Borough</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>ZipCode</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Address No</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Street</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Freeform</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList><asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" Width="150px">
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Borough</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>ZipCode</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Address No</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Street</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Freeform</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList><asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" Width="150px">
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Borough</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>ZipCode</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Address No</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Street</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Freeform</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

---

If Visual Studio tends to reformat it automatically, putting the line breaks back in the markup, here is another way to do it, using a table element:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="150px">
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Borough</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>ZipCode</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Address No</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Street</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Freeform</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" Width="150px">
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Borough</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>ZipCode</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Address No</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Street</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Freeform</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" Width="150px">
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Borough</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>ZipCode</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Address No</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Street</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Freeform</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: oh wow so the </> tag and another <> tag had to be in the same line. Wow thats genius man. Thanks.

Comment: I've used this solution to replace messy things like negative margins or positioning.

Comment: i tried the table element but it kept giving me an html warning. but i just tried your example. made my html look so much cleaner. thanks @ConnorsFan